# Handle OAuth signup/login when email exist

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, openid

Problem assumptions/conditions:

1. There exists a user with email `foo@bar.com` (unverified) in the system.
2. Visitor is not signed into the system (no current session, e.g. new browser).
3. Visitor signup/login using Google Account, through OAuth (user authorizes).
4. The system receives callback with uid and the email `foo@bar.com` [verified by Google].

I see three options here:

A. Sign in the visitor to the existing account with email foo@bar.com. This have some security implications.

B. Ask for a password [assuming there is a password in the system, this may not be the case with multiple OAuth providers] and sign them into existing account if it's valid.

C. Reject the login/signup, say email is already used, encourage user to login before connecting with Google.

**What are the security risks with option #A?**

*What I've come up with myself:*

'Anticipation attacks' could be performed, where an attacker anticipates a signup and creates an account on the system before the target does. After the target has signed up using OAuth he will have an active session on that account. Would be defeated by clearing all sessions on the account before doing #A.

Comment: Why do you allow step 1, i.e. a user account with an unverified email address? Is that user allowed to login? Is it because you'd like a simple onboarding process with no email verification? — Anyway the anticipation attack is an interesting attack I think. In my app, I do require people to verify their emails though and your question indicates to me that verifying the email seems like a good idea.

Comment: Was this ever resolved as safe for Facebook and Google oauths that verify emails cleanly?

Answer (score 1):

When the user logged in through OAuth in Google, you can be sure that the email address you get back from Google really belongs to that user. So the thing you seem to worry about is that the user already known on your system by that email address does not own that email address. That should have been caught by the time he signed up, with an email conversation. But if it isn't, you might want to reset the password and send an email to the genuine user that you did so, and for what reasons. You may also want to log the user out if he is currently logged in. The user can still access his data, but only through his OAuth login session, or by responding to the email. The email should state that it is a precaution, as there is no way to find out if it really is the same person.

Comment: Sending an email will serve no purpose, because it would be sent to the user authenticating through OAuth.

Answer (score 1):

An "accidental attack" can happen too:

In step 1, the user who signed up with address `foo@bar.com`, in fact intended to type `fuu@bar.com`, but typed a typo: `foo` instead of `fuu`.

Now, the Google user signs up with Oauth and `foo@bar.com`, and in this way hijacks the account of the step-1 user. Accidentally :-) because of a typo made by the step-1 user.

So, either the step-1 user can anticipate-attack the Google user, or the Google user can accidentally-attack the step-1 user. (I cannot think of any other attacks at least not right now.)